# Can php use memory mapped file instead of shmop?

Tags: php, mmap

I'm a php newbie, AFAK there's only shmop api for share memory in php, but I do want a library for me to operate on memory mapped file, any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try this extension.
https://github.com/calcinai/php-ext-mmap

```
//mmap_open($file_name, $block_size, $offset)
$mmap = mmap_open('/dev/mem', 1024, 0);
```